# Basic Javascript validation

Tags: javascript

This is a really simple problem. I had this working and then i must of changed something and now it doesn't work. Its just a peice of JS code checking for an empty string. Here is the code below. It's been driving me mad for 20 minutes trying to figure out what is wrong with this ridicliously simple code.

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
 function validateForm(){
 var email= document.getElementById('email').value;
 if (email.length==''){
 alert("please fill out email");}}
    </script>

<form name="contact" method="post" action='ContactPHP.php'>
Your Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="validateForm()"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: It's easy to confuse name and id attributes.  Make a habit of always putting both

Answer (score 4):

Your javascript calls  `getElementById('email')` but your input does not have an id of 'email'.

Assign an id to it.

```
<input name='email' id='email' type='text' />
```

Answer (score 2):

`email.length` does not return a string. You are comparing it to an empty string. Either use `email == ""` or `email.length > 0`.

Additionally, your input element has `name` "email", but you're looking for an element with `id` "email".

Here's the full (corrected) snippet:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm(){
        var email= document.getElementById('email').value;
        if(email.value == '') {
            alert("please fill out email");
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="contact" method="post" action='ContactPHP.php'>
    Your Email: <input id='email' name='email' type='text' /><br />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="validateForm()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `name='email`' but are looking for the element with the ID of email...just add `id='email'` to your text input

Answer (score 0):

Your input for the email does not have an Id="email"

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use document.getElementById here.

Try this:

function validateForm(form){
 var email= form.email.value;
 if (email.length==''){
 alert("please fill out email");}}
    


Your Email:

Answer (score 0):

I am too lazy to check but I have the impression that even if the validation fails the form will submit because the javascript function does not return false;

I woudl return false after the alert('yadda yadda'); and change the onclick event handler to:

```
onclick="return validateForm();"
```